# Problem with the marginfit package and margin changes

Tags: floats, margins, memoir, marginpar

I am using the `memoir` package and make heavy use of margin notes (with `\marginpar`). I had a lot of issues with the placement of the notes until I discovered the very recent package [`marginfit`](https://ctan.org/pkg/marginfit), which does a significantly better job than `marginfix` and others.

However, the package seems to break `memoir`'s `\adjustwidth` functionality, in particular preventing me from using full-width figures (on *odd* pages only!). Here is an example of a full-width figure without `marginfit`:
[image: Without marginfit]
and here is what happens as soon as I load `marginfit`:
[image: With marginfit]

The code is as follows.

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{marginfit}

 \newlength{\fullwidthlen}
 \setlength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparwidth}
 \addtolength{\fullwidthlen}{\marginparsep}
 \newenvironment{fullwidth}{%
    \begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{-\fullwidthlen}%
 }{%
   \end{adjustwidth}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{fullwidth}
\rule{\linewidth}{1em}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{figure}

\marginpar{Donec vehicula augue eu neque.}

\lipsum[1]

\marginpar{Donec varius orci eget risus.}


\end{document}
```

The way `\adjustwidth` works is

```
\newenvironment{adjustwidth}[2]{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \topsep\z@%
    \listparindent\parindent%
    \parsep\parskip%
    \@ifmtarg{#1}{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\z@}}%
                 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{#1}}%
    \@ifmtarg{#2}{\setlength{\rightmargin}{\z@}}%
                 {\setlength{\rightmargin}{#2}}%
    }
    \item[]}{\end{list}}
```

Does anyone have ideas about how this problem could be fixed?

Comment: Well it get even worse of you start this MWE with `test \newpage`, then it also moves the lorem ipsum

Comment: Also which exact problems did you have with `\marginpar`? `memoir` has some extra tricks users tend to forget. Memoir does not address, problem 2, but the placement fixable using `\strictpagecheck`. I have no idea what that package is doing, and why a list inside a float can make everything behave so badly

Comment: @daleif I use `\marginpar` to place bibliographic references in the margin next to every `\cite`. Even with `\strictpagecheck`, the `\marginpar`s would often appear on the wrong margin, and it was difficult to manage the placement of the `\marginpar`s near the bottom of the page, etc. Loading `marginfit` immediately gets rid of all these problems for me.

Comment: I would like to see an example of a marginpar not in the right margin under strict (it takes a few compilations for it to settle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `\adjustwidth` enlarges the outputbox. To my understanding, this is not the correct behavior, but maybe it is not possible to do otherwise.

You can fix the problem with the following code in the preamble after loading `marginfit`.

```
\makeatletter
\let\my@makecol\marginfit@makecol
\def\marginfit@makecol{%
  \my@makecol%
  \wd\@outputbox\columnwidth%
}
\makeatother
```

I will update `marginfit` to handle that properly soon.